# SharePoint CAML Query returning non-existing files on SharePoint Cluster with CRM Integration

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dynamics-crm, caml, csom

I'm executing the following CAML query into a SharePoint library using CSOM to get all files in library with creation date equals to the current date, I'm doing this in different SharePoint sites and libraries without problems, but when I execute it into a clustered SharePoint integrated with Dynamics CRM I'm getting "non-existing" files, that means that the file isn't "physically" at the SharePoint folder.

Also, I already searched the file by applying some file filters in the List View but SharePoint cannot find the file in the library, also searched into the recycle bin but without success.

SharePoint instances have the same services running so the questions are Does the clustered factor influence in the query? or Does anyone knows any reason why I'm getting this "non-existing" files? Do I need to change my CAML query?

CAML Query

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
   <Query>
      <Where>
         <Geq>
             <FieldRef Name='Created' />
                 <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>
                    <Today/>
                 </Value>
          </Geq>
       </Where>
     </Query>
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='Title' />
   <FieldRef Name='URL' />
   <FieldRef Name='Created' />
</ViewFields>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the user searching has more access rights and you simply didn't see the entries because you don't have the proper access rights.